# How to use a related manager and reverse lookups to clean up this Django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have some working code, but have recently learned about Related Managers and reverse lookups and would like to know how to apply them to this code:

The hacky method I would like to utilize a Related Manager/reverse lookup is `get_by_type_for_user(self, user)`:

```
class BadgeAssertionQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def get_user(self, user):
        return self.filter(user = user)

    def get_type(self, badge_type):
        return self.filter(badge__badge_type = badge_type)

    ...

class BadgeAssertionManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
    return BadgeAssertionQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    ...

    def get_by_type_for_user(self, user):

        types = BadgeType.objects.all()
        qs = self.get_queryset().get_user(user)
        by_type =  [
                     {
                        'badge_type': t,
                        'list': qs.get_type(t)
                     } for t in types
                   ]

        return by_type
```

Where:

```
class BadgeAssertion(models.Model):
    badge = models.ForeignKey(Badge)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    ...
    objects = BadgeAssertionManager()
```

and:

```
class Badge(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    badge_type = models.ForeignKey(BadgeType)
    ....
```

and:

```
class BadgeType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    ...
```

What I'm using this for is to output, for a specific user, the badges they have earned, organized by badge type:

from view:

```
context['badge_assertions_by_type'] = BadgeAssertion.objects.get_by_type_for_user(profile_user)
```

snippet from template (this is the user's profile page):

```
    {% for badges in badge_assertions_by_type %}
        {{badges.badge_type.name}}    
          {% for assertion in badges.list %}
              {{assertion.badge.name}}
              {{assertion.time_issued}}
          {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Where is your `get_user()` and `get_type()` methods? It's not clear what's the later one is doing.

Comment: Thanks, details added. Added BadgeType model also.

Comment: I guess, you've misplaced the `BadgeAssertionManager()`. It should be in `BadgeAssertion`, not in `Badge`, as per your code.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  Fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your method like this:

```
def get_badges_by_type_for_user(self, user):        
    qs = self.get_queryset()
             .select_related('badge', 'badge__badge_type')
             .filter(user=user)
    badges = defaultdict(list)
    for badge_assertion in qs:
        badges[badge_assertion.badge.badge_type].append(badge_assertion.badge)
    return badges
```

You don't need to iterate over all the BadgeTypes available, but just group the assertions you get, in buckets of badge types. So, not filtration on `badge_type` is required. Notice the use of [`defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here. You can try this out, and see if it works. Haven't tested it myself.

The result structure is different here now. It's:

```
{
    badge_type1: [badge1, badge2, ...],
    badge_type2: [badge3, badge4, ...]
}
```

instead of:

```
[
    {'badge_type' : badge_type1, 'list': [badge1, badge2]},
    {'badge_type' : badge_type2, 'list': [badge3, badge4]}
]
```

The first one makes more sense here.

Comment: Thank you!  How can I loop through this structure in my template? I can't figure it out.