# Only display items with a unique attribute in a django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a list being displayed in a template:

EDIT: this is more complete code from the template:

```
{% for assertions in badge_assertions_by_type %}
    {{assertions.badge_type.name}}    
      {% for assertion in assertions.list %}
          {{assertion.badge.name}}
          {{assertion.time_issued}}
      {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

badge_assertions_by_type is [defined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420417/how-to-use-a-related-manager-and-reverse-lookups-to-clean-up-this-django-queryse/32420722).

`{{assertions.list}}` looks like this:

```
[<BadgeAssertion: MyBadge#1>, <BadgeAssertion: MyBadge#1>, <BadgeAssertion: MyBadge#1>, <BadgeAssertion: MyBadge#1>, <BadgeAssertion: MyBadge#2>]
```

Instead of displaying all of these items, I only want to display unique items, with a number showing how many, e.g instead of:

```
MyBadge#1
MyBadge#1
MyBadge#1
MyBadge#1
MyBadge#2
```

I want something like this, preferably done in the Template:

```
MyBadge#1 (x4)
MyBadge#2
```

The text being displayed is actually {{assertion.badge.name}}, which is the same as the BadgeAssertion model's `__str__` which is why it looks the same in {{assertions.list}}

assertions.list is coming from some other stuff higher up (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420417/how-to-use-a-related-manager-and-reverse-lookups-to-clean-up-this-django-queryse/32420722#32420722), there it is confusingly called badges.list)

The models:

```
class Badge(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    ...

class BadgeAssertion(models.Model):
    badge = models.ForeignKey(Badge)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Count with distinct**, like so:

```
assertions = BadgeAssertion.objects.all().annotate(Count('badge__name', 
                                         distinct=True))
```

[Docs for clarify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count.distinct)

Comment: This doesn't work: `for assertion in assertions: print(assertion.badge__name__count) ` results in `1` for all of them

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations
maybe it help

Comment: I've been studying that, and can't figure out how to make it work with this problem.... I will keep studying =)